# JBoss Wildfly 9 - Multiple Datasources and PersistenceUnits

Tags: datasource, wildfly, entitymanager, persistence-unit, wildfly-9

after upgrading from JBoss EAP 6.1 to JBoss Wildfly 9 I've got a problem with multiple XA-Datasources and the related PersistenceUnits.
I'm using an Oracle Database with different users/schemas. I've configured 2 XA-Datasources which are using the same Connection URL, but have different user-names.

*Datasource 1*

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/DS1" pool-name="DS1">
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">...@<host>:<port>:<ssid></xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
    <xa-pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
         <user-name>user1</user-name>
         <password>password1</password>
    </security>
</xa-datasource>
```

*Datasource 2*

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/DS2" pool-name="DS2">
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">...@<host>:<port>:<ssid></xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
    <xa-pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
         <user-name>user2</user-name>
         <password>password2</password>
    </security>
</xa-datasource>
```

In an EJB I've configured 2 EntityMangers using the defined datasources:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "DS1")
private EntityManager manager1;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "DS2")
private EntityManager manager2;
```

Now an error occurs when calling manager2.find(...) in my EJB. Debugging the code nothing happens and after a few minutes the TransactionReaper is shown in the server logfile. I think this occurs due to a timeout.
When changing one datesource-URL, e.g. replacing the `<host>` part with an IP or a second host-alias, everything works without any problems. The problem only occurs when the URLs of both datasources are identical. So I doubt that there is a general configuration problem.

Does anyone have any idea why this problem occurs?
If you need more information or configuration, please let me know.

*Datesource defintions in persistence.xml*

```
    <persistence-unit name="DS1" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jta-data-source>DS1</jta-data-source>
      <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>       
      <properties>

          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>

          <!-- ********* Transaction settings for CMT ******* --> 
          <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />

          <!--- ******** Log-Settings for SQL statements ******** -->
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
          <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />  
          <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />    

          <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>          

          <!-- ********* Deactivated Creation of Database structure on deployment ******* -->
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>  

          <!-- ********* Hibernate Caching ************  -->  
          <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />   
          <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value="false"/>      
          <!-- Query Caching is tricky and often harmful (even if turned on but not used)! See http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/ -->
          <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />

          <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="DS1"/>

          <!-- ********** Hibernate Search Properties ************** -->
          <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />    
          <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${jboss.home.dir}/appdata/.../indices" />  
          <property name="hibernate.search.default.optimizer.operation_limit.max" value="1000"/>          
          <property name="hibernate.search.worker.execution" value="async" />
          <property name="hibernate.search.worker.thread_pool.size" value="1" />
          <property name="hibernate.search.worker.buffer_queue.max" value="100" /> 

          <!-- **********  Hibernate Envers Properties ********** -->
          <property name="org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision" value="false" />
          <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix" value="AUD_" />
          <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix" value="" />         
          <property name="org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete" value="true" />
      </properties>    
   </persistence-unit>

   <persistence-unit name="DS2">
      <jta-data-source>DS2</jta-data-source>
      <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>       
      <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>

          <!-- ********* Transaction settings for CMT ******* --> 
          <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />

          <!--- ******** Log-Settings for SQL statements ******** -->
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
          <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />  

          <!-- ********* Deactivated Creation of Database structure on deployment ******* -->
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>  

          <!-- ********* Hibernate Caching ************  -->  
          <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />   
          <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
          <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="netportType"/>

      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

*Stacktrace*

```
    2016-02-10 10:31:12,961 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffc0a802a0:5fafdf86:56baffad:148 in state  RUN
2016-02-10 10:31:12,968 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffc0a802a0:5fafdf86:56baffad:148 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
2016-02-10 10:31:12,969 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffffc0a802a0:5fafdf86:56baffad:148 aborting with 1 threads active!
2016-02-10 10:31:13,037 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2016-02-10 10:31:13,038 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 1) IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLING_BACK
2016-02-10 10:31:13,039 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (EJB default - 1) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
2016-02-10 10:31:13,041 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2016-02-10 10:31:13,042 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 1) IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLING_BACK
2016-02-10 10:31:13,466 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffc0a802a0:5fafdf86:56baffad:148 in state  CANCEL
2016-02-10 10:31:13,467 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012378: ReaperElement appears to be wedged: java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:308)
oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:345)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:223)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIOtxen.doOTXEN(T4CTTIOtxen.java:168)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource.doTransaction(T4CXAResource.java:746)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource.doRollback(T4CXAResource.java:624)
oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.rollback(OracleXAResource.java:936)
org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.rollback(XAManagedConnection.java:346)
org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.rollback(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:196)
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelAbort(XAResourceRecord.java:368)
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:2993)
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:2972)
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.Abort(BasicAction.java:1675)
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.cancel(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:127)
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.cancel(AtomicAction.java:215)
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper.doCancellations(TransactionReaper.java:381)
com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.coordinator.ReaperWorkerThread.run(ReaperWorkerThread.java:78)

2016-02-10 10:31:13,983 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffc0a802a0:5fafdf86:56baffad:148 in state  CANCEL_INTERRUPTED
2016-02-10 10:31:13,984 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012120: TransactionReaper::check worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] not responding to interrupt when cancelling TX 0:ffffc0a802a0:5fafdf86:56baffad:148 -- worker marked as zombie and TX scheduled for mark-as-rollback
2016-02-10 10:31:13,985 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012110: TransactionReaper::check successfuly marked TX 0:ffffc0a802a0:5fafdf86:56baffad:148 as rollback only
2016-02-10 10:33:09,469 ERROR [<BEAN-Name>] (EJB default - 1) org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1694)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1141)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.find(AbstractEntityManager.java:213)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:634)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:331)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:202)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.isAutoCommit(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterNonTransactionalQuery(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterOperation(SessionImpl.java:503)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2594)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:991)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_ROLLING_BACK
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:241)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:1898)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:1913)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getAutoCommit(WrappedConnection.java:805)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.isAutoCommit(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:322)
    ... 86 more
```

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace?  and your persistence.xml configuration with both units?

Comment: Can you show as whole Datasource Definitions ?

Comment: I've added the information to the post (at the end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following parameters to the  in the datasource configuration solved the problem:

```
<is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
<no-tx-separate-pools />
```